# WCF service slow response after less than 5 minutes idle (4.0 on Azure)

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, azure

I have a WCF service with 2 endpoints using BasicHttpBinding running on an instance in Azure. When the service is called for the first time it takes 13-16 seconds for a response (which is to be expected) and subsequent requests are adequate at between 150ms and 1000ms depending on the request type (I am using soapUI for testing).

But if I do not send any requests **for a few minutes** (**less than 4 or 5** minutes) the service instance does not appear to be getting reused as it is taking as long as the first request of 13+ seconds.

I have tried "InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single" in my ServiceBehavior(s) but that did not fix the problem.

In the trace I can see that the **thread id changes** whenever the service gives a slow response.

I have also logged the time from when Application_BeginRequest is hit to the start of the method being called by the client which seems to be the largest delay during these 'slow' calls.
I have some fairly large classes representing business interfaces and am using Entity Framework for a MySQL database running on an Azure VM. (Although I don't think this is necessarily an Azure issue).

The slow responses are the same whether I am calling a complex message type linked to DB operations or just a simple "Hello World" response.

- Even if a new instance of the service is required **should it take as long as an initial load after an IIS restart or application pool recycle?**
- Would doing some magic using wrappers for Static classes help? (I'm thinking not).

Built with C#  4.0 / VS2010 Professional

Answer (score 2):

There can be lots of reasons why this is happening. I suggest you start with some [tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526.aspx) in your WCF service.

- Add some logging in your application using **TraceSource**:

  ```
  private TraceSource ts = new TraceSource("MyApp");

  public string GetData(int value)
  {
      ts.TraceInformation("GetData called with {0}", value);

      return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
  }
  ```
- Configure the TraceSource in your web.config together with the System.ServiceModel source.

---

```
 <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="MyApp" switchValue="All">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="All" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="Logs.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" name="xml" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
  </system.diagnostics>
```

---

- Open the svclog file and you'll be able to see a detailed overview of everything that's happing in your service and how long each little step takes. This should help you to poinpoint the issue.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sandrino. I did actually already enable tracing but I didn't try using TraceInformation - I was using a static method to write to a debug table in my database. And that's when you made realize that debug method was masking a problem - it was slowing down my 'Hello World' test because it was doing the DB call.
So the main issue looks like MySQL going idle. I have set Min Pool Size=1 in the MySQL connection string and this has now reduced the response after idle from 13-15 seconds to around 4 or 5 seconds for any DB-backed message